# Generate Array Randomly only Once a Day

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to generate random array but once a day and should not be repeated next day or on same date next month. Here is my code...

```
function Rand1($min, $max, $quantity) {
srand(date("ymd"));
$first = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H");
shuffle($first);
return array_slice($first, 0, $quantity);
}
$three_array=Rand1(0,8,3);
$three_string=implode(" ",$three_array);
echo $three_string;
```

It generate D H F for the same day and next day and so on.
If I remove this - srand(date("ymd")) then it shows randomly on each page load.
But it **string should not change for the 24 hours**, like this:

If date is 01/06/2019 - D H F

If date is 02/06/2019 - A E B (Any other random order)

If date is 01/07/2019 - B D F (Any other random order)

How can I get this without database or cookie, it should be based on PHP.

Comment: Without any storage it is __impossible__. PHP does not know about previous executions of PHP.

Comment: Try a simple hash of the current year-month-day values, and use that hash to seed the RNG.  The hash value will be the same for 24 hours and will then change when the date changes.  Something like the [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) or similar simple hash should work fine.

Comment: can you show the code #rossum

Comment: Your code works for me. For `190601`, I got consistently `D B G`. For `190602` I got consistently `H F B`, and so on.